# Cannot write into textfield, page will be reload into the first tab - flutter

Tags: textfield, tabbar

i have tabbar in flutter and textfield into 2 tabs. after i click to write under textfield in the second tab, page reload and take me back to the first tab.once i click in textfield , keyboard appear and directly page reload and first Tab appear.

I tried : return Scaffold(
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
body: SingleChildScrollView(
physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),

still not working